# HTML Form is being doubled every single time I hit a jQuery.append function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, append

I am trying to create a form with one input field for the users task and 3 select options for the hour, minute, and AM / PM of the task. I want to create a button that will add the same form below it, so that the user can input another task with the same exact fields. The problem is that whenever I use the jQuery append function on the button, it is doubling the appending of the form. How can I make it that the form is generated only once after the button is clicked by the user? Down below is my code for the form and the Javascript:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post">
        <div class="form-group" style="text-align:center">
            <h4>Task</h4>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Task" name="taskname" required>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="form-group">
            <h4 style="text-align:center">What time do you want me to remind you about this task?</h4>
                <center>
                    <select name="remind_endtime_hour" required>
                        <option value="00">00</option>
                        <option value="01">01</option>
                        <option value="02">02</option>
                        <option value="03">03</option>
                        <option value="04">04</option>
                        <option value="05">05</option>
                        <option value="06">06</option>
                        <option value="07">07</option>
                        <option value="08">08</option>
                        <option value="09">09</option>
                        <option value="10">10</option>
                        <option value="11">11</option>
                        <option value="12">12</option>
                    </select>

                    <select name="remind_endtime_minute" required>
                        <option value="00">00</option>
                        <option value="01">01</option>
                        <option value="02">02</option>
                        <option value="03">03</option>
                        <option value="04">04</option>
                        <option value="05">05</option>
                        <option value="06">06</option>
                        <option value="07">07</option>
                        <option value="08">08</option>
                        <option value="09">09</option>
                        <option value="10">10</option>
                        <option value="11">11</option>
                        <option value="12">12</option>
                        <option value="13">13</option>
                        <option value="14">14</option>
                        <option value="15">15</option>
                        <option value="16">16</option>
                        <option value="17">17</option>
                        <option value="18">18</option>
                        <option value="19">19</option>
                        <option value="20">20</option>
                        <option value="21">21</option>
                        <option value="22">22</option>
                        <option value="23">23</option>
                        <option value="24">24</option>
                        <option value="25">25</option>
                        <option value="26">26</option>
                        <option value="27">27</option>
                        <option value="28">28</option>
                        <option value="29">29</option>
                        <option value="30">30</option>
                        <option value="31">31</option>
                        <option value="32">32</option>
                        <option value="33">33</option>
                        <option value="34">34</option>
                        <option value="35">35</option>
                        <option value="36">36</option>
                        <option value="37">37</option>
                        <option value="38">38</option>
                        <option value="39">39</option>
                        <option value="40">40</option>
                        <option value="41">41</option>
                        <option value="42">42</option>
                        <option value="43">43</option>
                        <option value="44">44</option>
                        <option value="45">45</option>
                        <option value="46">46</option>
                        <option value="47">47</option>
                        <option value="48">48</option>
                        <option value="49">49</option>
                        <option value="50">50</option>
                        <option value="51">51</option>
                        <option value="52">52</option>
                        <option value="53">53</option>
                        <option value="54">54</option>
                        <option value="55">55</option>
                        <option value="56">56</option>
                        <option value="57">57</option>
                        <option value="58">58</option>
                        <option value="59">59</option>
                    </select>

                    <select name="remind_endtime_AM_PM" required>
                        <option value="AM">AM</option>
                        <option value="PM">PM</option>
                    </select>
                    <hr>
                </center>
        </div>
    </form>
    <center><a href="#" id="addMore">+ Add Another Task</a></center>
    <br>
    <br>
    <center><input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" style="width: auto; height: auto; font-size: 25px; text-align: center;" required></center>
</body>
```

Javascript

```
<script>
    jQuery("#addMore").click(function(){
        var contents = jQuery("form").html();
        jQuery('form').append(contents);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `one()` method to listen only once.

```
 jQuery("#addMore").one('click', function(){
    // .....
 });
```

---

**UPDATE 1:** It's duplicating existing form elements so the second time it will duplicate the previously appended elements as well. So in order to fix cache the HTML in a variable.

```
var contents = jQuery("form").html();

jQuery("#addMore").click(function(){
    jQuery('form').append(contents);
});
```

---

**UPDATE 2:** For adding a remove button simply wrap elements within a div and keep a close button within it. Bind click event handler for the button to remove the newly added form section.

```
var contents = `<div> <button class="remove" type="button">X<button>
                 ${jQuery("form").html()}
                </div>`;

jQuery("#addMore").click(function(){
    jQuery('form').append(contents);
});

// listener for remove button, with help of event delegation
jQuery('form').on('click', '.remove',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Comment: This method made it that it would only generate another form but not another after. I don' t think that's what I was looking for.

Comment: Thank you so much this works. But whenever I click on the button, the page refreshes and everything gets deleted. How do I make it that only one of them gets deleted and the others are still remaining?

Comment: @YashBob : set its type as button or add `event.preventDefault()` ..... check updated answer

Comment: This works but now the problem is that the whole form has become a button with an outline and stuff.

Comment: @YashBob : you can customize as per your requirement using css... button can also be replaced with an icon.

Comment: Given this code, how could I now insert the appended data into a PHP database? Would it be the same as regularly inserting into a database? I know how to insert data from the fields given a regular HTML form, but in this case, there are new fields being creating but since they don't have variables to them, what would I do?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add the same form every time you click on button then you need to change little in you're jQuery code

```
<script>
var contents = jQuery("form").html();
    jQuery("#addMore").click(function(){

        jQuery('form').append(contents);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: This worked perfectly fine! I was wondering, how can I also add a remove button that would essentially remove the last form the user added?

Comment: jQuery("form").last().remove();

Comment: Contact me to get in touch with me https://nishit-manjarawala.com/